# How to Build a Drawer with a DrawerHeader and a ListView.builder

Tags: for-loop, flutter, dart, widget, for-in-loop

EDIT 2:
After spending the whole day on this. I finally managed to work with the ListView.builder and my initial problem is no longer a problem... :). But now a more specific problem appeared.
Apparently all trouble I was facing was due the use of a DrawerHeader and the ListView.builder together on the same drawer. All my attempts result in a lot of different types of errors. Can anybody tell me how to insert a drawer header on the code below without errors?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  List<String> items = [
    'Alimentação', 'Artigos para o lar', 'Beleza', 'Carros',
    'Computadores', 'Consertos', 'Construção', 'Ensino',
    'Esporte', 'Pet', 'Presentes', 'Religião',
    'Saúde', 'Serviços Gráficos', 'Serviços para o lar', 'Serviços profissionais',
  ];

  List<IconData> icones = [
    Icons.play_arrow, Icons.list, Icons.create_new_folder, Icons.add_alarm,
    Icons.insert_comment, Icons.drag_handle, Icons.ac_unit, Icons.adjust,
    Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra, Icons.forum, Icons.gamepad, Icons.hd,
    Icons.format_align_justify, Icons.keyboard, Icons.list, Icons.mail,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Teste de app',
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[i]),
              leading: Icon(icones[i]),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(
            'Texto'
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

EDIT 1:
After the first help, I've managed to put the lists using a ScrollView.builder, but the menu is not scrolling anymore. After some research I wrapped the ScrollView inside a SizedBox with fixed height and it worked. The only problem is that fixed height. I'm sure this is not the most apropriate way of doing it but when I change the fixed height for double.infinity I get an error:

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
//----------------TEST--------------------------------
class TestDrawer extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: kCategorias.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, int index){
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  kCategorias[index],
                ),
                leading: Icon(kIcones[index]),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

To contextualize, I've started studying Flutter and finally I felt confident enough to "play" on my very first project. It's a simple catalog of instagram accounts of companies that work with delivery. If I manage to finish, I will launch the app on the store to help the local companies to deal with the pandemy and the social isolation.

ATM I'm working on the Drawer of the application and everything is working pretty well. But I got stuck. I want to create a menu of categories. The menu items are ListTiles. I have two lists to manage this menu. One list with the names of the categories and another one with the icons of each one of the categories. On a future moment I'll need a third list with the links for each menu item.

Well, all I need to do is iterate each one of these lists inside each ListTile item. The categories list worked 100%. The problem started when I tried to iterate the second list inside the same ListTile widget.

The first thing that came to my mind to solve this was of course create a single for loop and inside it using as many lists as I wanted with the same index. I tested this possibility in the DartPad and it worked perfectly! It returned exactly the way I wanted. The problem is that in order to work I need to use the for... loop and when I transfered the same idea to my app code it only worked with the single line structure (without the curly brackets). Once I put the curly brackets, it returns an error *(The element type `'Set<ListTile>'` can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.)* But if I use the single line structure I'm not able to iterate more than one list. The only possible way (in my mind) to iterate 2 or more list is using the curly brackets form.

I don't know if I was clear enough but, how can I solve this problem? How can I iterate 2 or more lists inside a single Widget - in my case ListTile() - using a for loop?

Below I'll attach the source code of the class I'm in trouble with. 
If you want to see the whole project and test [here](https://github.com/aanfiel/entregasemsobral/) is the link of the project repo on github.

Thx in advance!

```
//Builds a Drawer item using ListTile()
class BuildDrawerTile extends StatelessWidget {

List<String> list;
BuildDrawerTile({@required this.list});

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    for(String item in list ) ListTile( //HERE EVERYTHING WORKS WELL AS I'M NOT USING CURLY BRACKETS
      title: Text(
        item,
        style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF808080),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      leading: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), //HERE I NEEDED TO ITERATE SPECIFIC ICONS FOR EACH ITEM
      trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pop(context); //IN THE FUTURE HERE I'LL ITERATE A THIRD LIST WITH THE DESTINATIONS
      },
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am little bit in dilemma that what do you mean by you want to iterate through icons and destinations but i am answering base on what i understand.

You can display data using multiple list view if data is in sequence and length of data is same.

you can use simple listview to achieve it. i hope following code may help you.
if you have any query’s feel free to ask.

```
   List<String> items = [
    'Alimentação', 'Artigos para o lar', 'Beleza', 'Carros',
    'Computadores', 'Consertos', 'Construção', 'Ensino',
    'Esporte', 'Pet', 'Presentes', 'Religião',
    'Saúde', 'Serviços Gráficos', 'Serviços para o lar', 'Serviços profissionais',
  ];

  List<IconData> icones = [
    Icons.play_arrow, Icons.list, Icons.create_new_folder, Icons.add_alarm,
    Icons.insert_comment, Icons.drag_handle, Icons.ac_unit, Icons.adjust,
    Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra, Icons.forum, Icons.gamepad, Icons.hd,
    Icons.format_align_justify, Icons.keyboard, Icons.list, Icons.mail,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Teste de app',
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[i]),
              leading: Icon(icones[i]),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(
            'Texto'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Using ListView.builder worked fine and I managed to view the lists. The only problem is that now I lost the scroll functionality. The drawer is frozen. After some readings and search I managed to solve this problem using a sizedbox with fixed height. But I'm sure that this is not the most appropriate way of coding. Would you mind to help me?

Comment: It will automatically scroll fill more data until it can't fit in screen.

Comment: That's the point. I actually filled with more data (19 items) and It was not scrolling. I updated the problem on the main post. Would appreciate your help a lot. Thx!

Comment: @JoséLopes it is working completely fine. i added gif  of result.

Comment: Thank You soooo much. With your help I managed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just move your ListTile build logic in different method.

```
//Builds a Drawer item using ListTile()
class BuildDrawerTile extends StatelessWidget {

  List<String> list;
  BuildDrawerTile({@required this.list});

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: _buildList(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildList() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for(String item in list ) {
      widgets.add(ListTile( //HERE EVERYTHING WORKS WELL AS I'M NOT USING CURLY BRACKETS
        title: Text(
          item,
          style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF808080),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        leading: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), //HERE I NEEDED TO ITERATE SPECIFIC ICONS FOR EACH ITEM
        trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.pop(context); //IN THE FUTURE HERE I'LL ITERATE A THIRD LIST WITH THE DESTINATIONS
        },
      ),);
    }

    return widgets;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support Zakir. Apparently the problem lies in putting together the DrawerHeader() and the ListView.Builder() together on the same Drawer. I'm still having trouble on how to make it work because the Widget Drawer() only accepts a child, so I have no idea how to put them both under the same drawer. All my attempts have been a failure until now. It only works when I take the DrawerHeader out of the drawer. Then the ListView.Builder works perfectly.

Comment: You use a `Column` that has two children. The first is the header, the second is the list (whether the second uses a `ListView` or a `ListView.builder` is irrelevant, that only depends on how it's more comfortable for you to build the items).

Comment: Alternatively, you could make your builder return a `DrawerHeader` for index 0 and whatever else (probably `ListTile`s) for the rest but there's no real need for a hack like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while. But I got it using a `Column` with a `DrawerHeader` and an `Expanded`, inside the `Expanded` I put my `ListView.builder`. It worked here.

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(child: Text(controller.user.firstName)),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controller.orderList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                OrderEntity order = controller.orderList[i];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Pedido nº " + order.id.toString()),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    )),
```